# How to send data from a html5 form to php page to process without having to reload the page or to go to the php page

Tags: php, html

I am building a website and in some section I need the user to choose three options of three select elements in the page and click on the search button to search in the database for what the user wants.. but the php do not get the data from the form without setting the type of the button to submit .. and this causes the button to reload the page .. but I do not want the page to be reloaded.

I have tried to setting the action of the form to be the php file that processes the data but this made it worse and redirected the user to the php file if hits the search button

the html code for the form

```
<form method="post">
   <select class="select_box">
     <option value="Choose a category">Choose a category</option>
     <option value="category1">category1</option>
     <option value="category2">category2</option>
     <option value="category3">category3</option>
   </select>
   <select class="select_box">
     <option value="Choose a place">Choose a place</option>
     <option value="place1">place1</option>
     <option value="place2">place2</option>
     <option value="place3">place3</option>
     <option value="place4">place4</option>
   </select>
   <select class="select_box">
     <option value="Choose budget">Choose budget</option>
     <option value="budget1">budget1</option>
     <option value="budget2">budget2</option>
     <option value="budget3">budget3</option>
     <option value="budget4">budget4</option>
   </select>
   <button type="button" name="search_btn">Search</button>
</form>
```

I expect the page no to reload and show the data based on the search done by the php file, but what actually happens is that the page reloads but and the expected data appears in the place specified for it

Comment: have a look at javascript's fetch api

Comment: Have a look at Javascript.

Comment: but I want to pass the data to the php file to search in the data base

Comment: That's right. You have to write JS script which will send your data to the backend and receive some data as response without reloading a page

Comment: Yep that's what the fetch API can do (despite the not very helpful name, it's actually just a new interface for AJAX calls where you can send and receive any data you wish without reloading).

Comment: One other thing you need is to give a NAME and an ID to your dropdown boxes, or JavaScript won't know how to talk to them:  <select class="select_box" id="choosebudget" name="choosebudget">

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ajax as it allows you to update a web page without reloading the page

Add this inside your event

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'yourphpfile.php',
  //get or post
  type: 'post',
  data: {
   //name & password optional
    name: 'yourinputdata',
    password: 'yourinputpassword'..
  },
  success: function(response) {
    location.reload(); // reloading page
  }
});
```

In the php file, use isset($_POST['name']) and isset($_POST['password'])  to ensure you are receiving the values and manipulate them as you wish.

Comment: what does the part of the name: .... and the password: .... refers to in the $.ajax

Comment: It can be anything..in your case, it can be category , place or budget
and then in your php file..add isset($_POST['category '])

Comment: okay... it seems to be that what is between the quotes will be sent to the php file

Comment: but how can I make it depends on the value that the user chooses from the select box.... to be able to process it in the php file and search in the database for the user's request

Comment: You retrieve the value chosen from the select box and save it in a variable. E.g cat: $category,
In php file:-
echo $_POST['cat'];
once you are able to see your value, you can do whatever you want.

Comment: you mean that I can I can replace (name: 'yourinputdata') with (category_choosen : $category ) that is in the javascript file, and then in the php file I can know what the user choosed by using the varivable (category_choosen)

Comment: yes if your $category' holds the value 5, then in the your php file $_POST[category_choosen] will equal to 5.

Comment: can you just type the code for the javascript file and the php file based on the html of the form provided above and the goal is to take the value of the select boxes ( lets say that the user choose catergory1 and place1 and budget1 ) and then print it on the screen without reloadin the page

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called AJAX.  What you do is use JavaScript to post the contents of the form, and the function waits for the response from the PHP page.

Here is a snippet of code that I use for just this reason.  You can easily modify this to fit in your own form:

```
    function sendMessage(formName) {
//Put the name of your form here - make sure your FORM has a NAME and ID tag
        formIs = document.quoteSubmitForm;

          var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
             //Run this part to display the response to the user.
             innercontent = "<span class='close' onclick='closeModal()'>&times;</span>" + xhttp.responseText;
             document.getElementById("modalContent").innerHTML = innercontent;
            }

          };
//Use this to fill in the name of the PHP which you intend to POST to.
          xhttp.open("POST", "quotes/submitnew.php");
          xhttp.send(new FormData (formIs));
        }
```